# Solving M digits Recursively from the left

Tags: python, recursion

Hi guys I have managed to solved recursively from R -> L:

> nth_digit(1, 12345) => 5
>   nth_digit(3, 12345) => 3 
>   nth_digit(4, 12345) => 2 
>   nth_digit(10, 12345) => None

and was wondering if there was a way to solve it recursively from L -> R such that:

> nth_digit(1, 12345) => 1 
>   nth_digit(3, 12345) => 3 
>   nth_digit(4, 12345) => 4

I've created a base case but not sure how am i going to solve the recursive part.

```
def mth_digit(m, num):
s = str(num)
if m == 0 or m > len(s):
    return None
elif m == 1:
    return num // 10**(len(s)-m)
else:
    #need help here
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
def mth_digit(m, num):
s = str(num)
if m == 0 or m > len(s):
    return None
if m == 1:
    return num // 10**(len(s)-1)
else:
    return mth_digit(m-1, num % (10**(len(s)-1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use powers of 10 and reduce the size of the number until it has the number of digits corresponding to the position you need.  Then the result will be the last digit of the remaining number.  If the number is not large enough for an nth digit from the left, this will return None.

For example:

```
def nthDigit(d,N):
    if N >= 10**d     : return nthDigit(d,N//10)
    if N >= 10**(d-1) : return N%10
```

output:

```
for i in range(1,7):
   print( i,nthDigit(i,1234) )

1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 None
6 None
```

You can also do it using only multiplications and divisions:

```
def nthDigit(d,N,p=1):
    if d>0      : return nthDigit(d-1, N, p*10)
    if N>=p     : return nthDigit(d, N//10, p)
    if N>=p//10 : return N%10
```

Of course you could also cheat and use a string, but that won't require recursion at all:

```
def nthDigit(d,N): return str(N)[d-1:d]
```